# What does this Java Program do?

Tags: java, regex

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\@[^\\@]+\\@").matcher(myMsg);
while (m.find()){
  totalPlaceHoldersList.add(m.group().toString());
}
```

I have this program with me. What does it do? Can someone explain it to me with examples?

Comment: What part of this don't you understand and can't find in the docs? It's a pretty common use of a regex matcher.

Comment: Try it. Let `myMsg` be `"foo @boo@ mu @bar@ baz"`, and at the end, print `totalPlaceHoldersList` to your console to see what it contains.

Answer (score 4):

It will match `myMsg` variable against that regular expression. Then it will add the results (if found something that matches the pattern) in a list.

Comment: MikkoP, I slightly rephrased it. When talking about regex patterns, one doesn't 'compare', but 'match'.

Answer (score 1):

This code processes the String myMsg. Finds all occurrences of substrings between the following separator: '\@', and puts these into a list called totalPlaceHoldersList.

Lets suppose you have this myMsg:

```
myMsg = 'bla bla \@value1\@ bla bla \@value2\@ bla bla';
```

After running the code, you will have the following values in `totalPlaceHoldersList`:

```
["value1", "value2"]
```

Note that this code won't compile and run because `totalPlaceHoldersList` is not declared. You would declare it like:

```
List<String> totalPlaceHoldersList = new ArrayList<String>();
```